# Two simple questions about application manifest and assembly of Visual Studio project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, manifest, .net-assembly, assemblies

I created a simple Win Form project, MyApp, with Visual Studio 2013 & C# .NET.

In order for the app to target Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019, I included an app (executable) manifest for the app's executable. Then, in the  section of the manifest, I added a `<supportedOS>` element for Windows 10.

Now, my two questions are:

1. Does the MyApp.exe.manifest file generated after success building have to be deployed to the same folder as the MyApp.exe?
2. In the app manifest file, should the '**assemblyIdentity version/name**' be the **same** as the Assembly version/name of my project?

I left the default value, version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app", for them. To my surprise, it seems to work no problem.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You should really consider upgrading VS, the Community edition is free of charge.

Comment: Thank you. I have both VS2019 and VS2013 on my PC. I am just not clear about app manifest usage.

Comment: Now I found that 'Application manifests should be included as a resource in the application's EXE file or DLL.' So, I think that MyApp.exe.manifest file doesn't have to be deployed to destination PC folders. But if thus, why is the MyApp.exe.manifest file created after building? It seems to be unnecessary.

Comment: No, the manifest gets embedded as an unmanaged resource in the .exe file.  And no, the OS requires that the entry exists, but its content only plays a role in a scenario that does not apply to managed code.